# Woher stammt das schwäbische Wort "Gugg" für Tüte?

Tags: etymology, dialect, swabian

Im Schwäbischen hört man vor allem auf dem Land oder an Markttagen:

> "Brauchet Se a Gugg?" - "Noi, i hab mei Tasch derbei"
>
> <sup>"Brauchen Sie eine Tüte?" - "Nein, ich habe meine Tasche dabei"</sup>

Daraus wird auch im Dialekt deutlich, dass mit *"Gugg"* eine Einkaufstüte gemeint ist und nicht etwa eine Tasche.

Neben Wörtern alemannischen Ursprungs gibt es im Schwäbischen auch eine Reihe von Lehnwörtern aus dem Französischen oder aus anderen Nachbarsprachen. Diese möchten aber bei dem Wort *"Gugg"* nicht recht passen. Da es ein altes Wort ist, hat es auch nichts mit der Plastiktüte zu tun, für die eine *"Gugg"* heute steht.

Wo hat eine *"Gugg"* ihre sprachliche Wurzel?

Comment: Der Ausdruck "Gugg" ist übrigens auch im Oberpfälzischen gebräuchlich.

Comment: Interessanter Link zur 'Tüte': http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_2/f13b/index.html - Das Ergebnis für den deutschen Südwesten kann ich allerdings nicht bestätigen. Ich kenne dort nur die 'Guggele' oder 'Plaschtigguggele'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nach einiger Recherche bin ich noch auf interessante Zusammenhänge gestoßen.

Die französische [*coque*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1329/woher-stammt-das-schwabische-wort-gugg-fur-tute/1330#1330) ist hier vermutlich eine Kurzform für [*cocqueluchon*](http://books.google.de/books?id=LBM7AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=coque%20cucullus&source=bl&ots=CG5dnBguyv&sig=XGgrIzTLZVnOfH8gDcuNxTrp01U&hl=de&ei=Hf8EToDfDZDFswaA8MzaDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&sqi=2&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=coqueluchon%20cucullus&f=false), eine Kapuze oder Beutelkappe, wie sie auch das mittelalterliche [Gugel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugel_%28Kleidung%29) ist. Beide Wörter stammen von dem lateinischen [*cucullus*](http://de.pons.eu/latein-deutsch/cucullus) (Kapuze, **Tüte**) ab. Eine Gugel wird heute nur noch in der [schwäbisch-alemannischen Fasnet](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrenattribute#Gugel.2FNarrenkappe) getragen.

[image]

<sup>Quelle [Wikimedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Wappen_Gueglingen.svg): Gugel im Wappen von Güglingen.</sup>

Es ist anzunehmen, dass im schwäbischen Dialekt die *coque*, das *Gugel* und der *cucullus* zur *Gugg* geworden ist. So wird auch die Bedeutung Tüte verständlich, denn in einer Kapuze kann man wie in einem Beutel Sachen verstauen.

Comment: Und der Gugelhupf?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: ganz richtig, der auch.

Answer (score 11):

Ich habe in der Zeitschrift "Blätter des Schwäbischen Albvereins" (hier das [PDF der Ausgabe](http://www.schwaben-kultur.de/pdfs/2005-6.pdf)) folgendes gefunden (S. 19):

> **Französisches Schwäbisch (III)**
>
> [...] Gugg (coque = Tüte)

Da mein Französisch nicht besonders gut ist, kann ich nicht verifizieren, ob das Wort *coque* heute oder früher für Tüte verwendet wurde. Es gibt es in der Bedeutung von "Schale"  (Schutz) – also nicht ganz abwegig.

Hier als Bild:

[image: Gugg coque]

Comment: Hmm interessant! Ich kenne immerhin die kulinarische *coquillage* für Schalentiere (wer's mag).

Answer (score 4):

Auch in Basel (CH) wird für eine Tüte der Ausdruck *Gugge* oder *Güggli* als Diminutiv verwendet. Das [Schweizerische Idiotikon](http://www.idiotikon.ch/) gibt an, das Wort scheine zu *guggen* (bedeutet u.a. *auf einem Horn blasen*. Für weitere Bedeutungen empfehle ich die [Suche](http://www.idiotikon.ch/Register/) des Idiotikons) zu gehören, aber importiert zu sein.
Die Etymologie scheint in diesem Fall nicht genau geklärt zu sein.

Comment: sehr spannend, dass es in Basel auch eine Gugge gibt!

Comment: Einschließlich der *Guggamusik* (Art Faschingsblaskapelle), die sich auch ins Schwäbische verbreitet hat.

Comment: Das Idiotikon weist ebenfalls darauf hin, dass _Gugge_ zu _guggen_ in einem ähnlichen Bedeutungsverhältnis steht wie _Tüte_ zu _tuten_.

Answer (score 2):

Mir scheint ein Zusammenhang zwischen Tüte und Horn durchaus möglich, also insbesondere waren die alten Obsttüten bis in die 80er üblicherweise noch dreieckig (gefaltet) bzw Konisch gefüllt. Somit wäre ein gemeinsamer Nenner von Tüte, Kapuze und Horn schlicht die Spitze, konische Form.

Answer (score -1):

vgl. zu coquillage
auch:
ndl. (mindestens Zeeuws/zeeländisch) 'kokkels' (einfache Muschelsorte - äh... oder Meeres-Schnecken?)

sowie aus dem bekannten englischen Lied (IrishFolk):... crying cockels and mussels alive ... "

- Guggn (u. dgl.):(vergessen)
  steht ebenso in einigen ostfränk. wie auch anderen hochdt. Dialekten für: spitze Papiertüte.*

(Aber das wurde ja schon deutlich.)

Vermutlich hat man diese ursprünglich (ca. seit 18./19. Jh.? - jedenfalls, als es schon Makulaturpapier gab) an Marktstand oder so aus einem rechteckigen Stück Papier gefaltet. (vgl Fish and chips oder auch ndl. Pommes im Zeitungspapier!) ...
Der Vgl. zur Kukulle liegt da ja nicht fern!

*Quelle: eigene mdl. Recherche unter entsprechenden Sprechern.

Comment: Was ist denn da zu vergleichen? Was hat es mit Meeresschnecken oder Muscheln auf sich? Was ist eine Kukulle? Äh...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Stef! Danke für deinen Beitrag und herzlich Willkommen hier auf german.SE! Wenn ich es richtig verstehe, ist dein Beitrag eine Ergänzung zu den bereits existierenden Antworten, die frz. _coque_ als Ursprung ansehen. Mir scheint es, als ob deine Antwort mehr eine Theorie über die Etymologie des französischen Worts ist, als über die Herkunft von _Gugg_. Verstehe ich deine Antwort so richtig?

Comment: @userunknown Sei doch beim nächsten Mal bitte ein bisschen freundlicher, nicht nur aber insbesondere bei Leuten, die hier neu sind :) _Kukulle_ steht im Wörterbuch, z.B. hier: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kukulle